# How to populate Identity Framework tables & custom tables without getting Invalid object name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-code-first, dbcontext

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5 framework to implement a simple project. In that project, I would like to use Identity Framework Tables (users, roles, etc..) as well as customized tables (student, landlord, etc..).

I also would like to initialize the tables with some values, therefore I added the following function to my home controller:

```
    public void PopulateAspNetTables()
    {
        context = new ApplicationDbContext();

        // Define Users and insert them to IF database :
        // **********************************************
        var passwordHash = new PasswordHasher();
        string password = passwordHash.HashPassword("Password@123");

        ApplicationUser user1 = new ApplicationUser
        {
            UserName = "user1",
            Email = "user1@user1.com",
            PasswordHash = password
        };
        context.Users.AddOrUpdate(user1);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

as well as :

```
    public void PopulateOurDatabase()
    {

        dbCntxt = new DatabaseContext();

        stdnt = new Student {StudentID = 1, FirstName = "FN", LastName = "LN", Age = 27, Sex = "Male", ContactNumber = "123456", Email = "user1@gmail.com", AcademicYear = 1, AcademicDegree = "Electrical Engineering", AcademicSubject = "blabla" };
        dbCntxt.Students.AddOrUpdate(stdnt);
        dbCntxt.SaveChanges();
```

The previous two functions will be called in the Home Controller constructor:

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
    private DatabaseContext dbCntxt;
    private ApplicationDbContext context;


    private Student stdnt;


    public HomeController()
    {

        PopulateOurDatabase();
        PopulateAspNetTables();
    }
....
....
}
```

Now the problem is that whenever I call the two functions in the constructor, the first one works correctly, while the second one throws always an error :

```
SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.AspNetUsers'.
```

If I change the order in which I call the functions, AspNetUsers table would be created properly, while I get the same error regarding Student tables. This can be clearly seen in the Server Explorer !

Why is that happening?

And since I created my own context, does this occur because I'm using two different contexts ? What's the best practice in this case ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer for my question. I removed the InitialCatalog part of my connection string for some testing reason and forgot to add it again. After a lot of digging here and there I found out that,most likely, since I'm using two different contexts, I need to tell the Application which database to start with.
Therefore, InitialCatalog part **should** be there.

Answer (score 0):

**I did not test but use "using" keyword to close each connection.**

```
 public void PopulateOurDatabase()
{
   using (dbCntxt = new DatabaseContext())
   {
    stdnt = new Student {StudentID = 1, FirstName = "FN", LastName = "LN", 
    Age = 27, Sex = "Male", ContactNumber = "123456", Email = 
   "user1@gmail.com", AcademicYear = 1, AcademicDegree = "Electrical 
   Engineering", AcademicSubject = "blabla" };
    dbCntxt.Students.AddOrUpdate(stdnt);
    dbCntxt.SaveChanges();
   }
```